# Probability of time waiting for the bus

Tags: probability, expected-value

The time (in min.) to wait for my bus can be modeled as an exponential r.v.

I know that the average time I need to wait for the bus is 10 min.

What is the prob. that I would wait more than 15min?

My Attempt:

$X\text{~}Exp(\lambda)$: $f(x)=10e^{-10x}$

I know that $\mathbb{X}[E]=\int^\infty_{-\infty}xf(x)dx$, so I want to solve: (lower bound is 15 because we want to calculate the probability that we wait at least 15 min).

$$\int^\infty_{15}x(10e^{-10x})dx=\left[-\frac{(10x+1)e^{-10x}}{10}\right]^\infty_{15}=\frac{151e^{-150}}{10}$$

My concern is that this number is so incredibly small so I don't think I did it correctly. Can I get pointers in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: You must normalize your distribution first.

Comment: The mean of an exponentially distributed random variable $X$ with parameter $\lambda$ is given by $\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{1}{\lambda}.$ So, in your case $\lambda=\frac{1}{10}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$P(X \geq 15)=1-\int_{0}^{15}\frac{1}{10}e^{-\frac{1}{10}x}dx$$

Answer (score 1):

You're approaching the problem incorrectly:  The exponential should be $-t/10$.

[image]

$$\int\limits_{t=15}^\infty \frac{1}{10} e^{-t/10}\ dt = \frac{1}{e^{3/2}} \approx 0.22313.$$